# R: Equivalent ways of coding a formula of a lm with higher-order terms

Tags: r, lm, higher-order-functions, quadratic

To my knowledge, there are three possible ways to code for second-order (and higher-) terms in a formula.

We can use the function `I(..)`, the function `poly(..)` and we can construct ourself the variable of the second degree. My question is: How do these functions work?

```
set.seed(23)
A = rnorm(12)
B = 1:12
C = factor(rep(c(1,2,3),4))
B2=B^2
```

what is the equivalent of `lm(A~poly(B,2)*C)` when using `I(..)` or when using the variable `B2`?

The use of `raw=T` in the `poly(..)` function does not change anything to the results, correct?

Comment: `poly(B,2, raw=TRUE)` will not deliver the same result as `poly(B,2)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lm(A~B2*C)
```

or

```
lm(A~I(B^2)*C)
```

give you the result of squaring column B and then doing the regression. Using

```
poly(B,2)
```

does something completely different - see ?poly.

Edit to add:
`poly()` calculates orthogonal polynomials which are not the same as the standard polynomials derived from simply squaring, cubing etc. a number.

Comment: `poly(B,2, raw=TRUE)` can be used if you want "simple" polynomials.

Comment: @DieterMenne Does it mean that poly(B,2,raw=T) is equivalent to I(B^2) or to B+I(B^2)?

Answer (score 1):

Does it mean that poly(B,2,raw=T) is equivalent to I(B^2) or to B+I(B^2)?

Try:

```
x = 0:99
df = data.frame(x=x,y=rnorm(100)+0.1*x + 0.04*x*x)
lm(y~poly(x,2),data=df)
lm(y~poly(x,2,raw=TRUE),data=df)
lm(y~x+I(x^2),data=df)
```